# After turning on Send Scheduled Reminders and setting up a Membership Renewal Reminder, why am I getting all zeros in my Scheduled Reminders log?

Tags: civimember, scheduled-reminders

I am using CiviCRM 4.5.8 on Drupal 7. I get the feeling my scheduled renewal reminders are not going out. These are my settings:
[image: Send Scheduled Reminders on]

[image: Renewal Reminder set up]

[image: Details of renewal reminder]

[image: Send Scheduled Reminders log]

Are there some other parameters or settings I need?

Comment: First question: are you certain you have some memberships expiring in the next three weeks? :)

Comment: Good question. Yes, I have had memberships expiring periodically since I set this up. I did have Send Scheduled Reminders set to run daily, but just changed it to hourly. I don't know if that would have any bearing; it seems like it shouldn't.

Comment: Have you tried creating a dummy membership on one of your email addresses and setting expiration to be a few weeks away as a test?

Comment: I have not. That is an excellent idea. I will try that and report back. Thanks.

Comment: Can you try turning off the repeat functionality.  In the past, there was problem with the repeat functionality.    You may be able to isolate the problem. If need be you can set up several reminders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say you get the feeling...have you gone into Search > Find Activities > Activity Type of "Membership Renewal Reminder" to see what it lists?  I always check to see if it has recorded the activity.  That doesnt mean it has been emailed only that it was scheduled against that account.  Additionally my reminders show up in the Recent Items on the left side of CiviCRM.

Comment: That's it! Thank you @Hudson Essex Terraplane! I thought the log would indicate how many reminders it was sending out. For some reason it never occurred to me to go to Search > Find Activities > Activity Type of "Membership Renewal Reminder". I did that just now and found that it has in fact sent 10 reminder emails, including some weekly repeats. I also received a reminder at the test membership's email I set up (thank you @Laryn). I really appreciate the input from all of you!